# Lighting for a layered shadowbox

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting, emission

I am trying to model a shadowbox like the ones shown in the image below. However, I can't seem to get the lighting to filter through the various layers as you would expect. Right now I have an area light placed behind the object but I am unsure what else I need to do to achieve the desired effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: what I am going for]